# To use SQLite in memory with NHibernate, do I have to install anything?

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite

I know NHibernate has a driver for SQLite, but what do I have to install locally to use the in-memory version?

Comment: I just had a hell of a time with the file version of Sqlite and NHibernate. Every web request worked, but took forever and caused the app pool reset.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this

[SQL.Data.SqlLite version with NHibernate 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460045/sql-data-sqllite-version-with-nhibernate-2-1)

Answer (score 2):

No you don't have to install anything when you want to run in-memory. Just reference the dll (copy-local true)

The name of the dll is System.Data.SQLite.dll
You can download it at [source forge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/files/SQLite%20for%20ADO.NET%202.0/1.0.65.0/SQLite-1.0.65.0-binaries.zip/download)

I started using sqllite in-memory when I was browsing through the FluentNhibernate examples. So I copied it from FluentNhibernate. I use the following configuration:

```
FluentConfiguration configuration = Fluently.Configure()
  .Database(() =>
    SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
     .InMemory()
     .ProxyFactoryFactory("NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle")
     .Mappings(mappingConfiguration => mappingConfiguration
     .FluentMappings
     .AddFromAssemblyOf<User>()); 
SessionSource sessionSource = new SingleConnectionSessionSourceForSQLiteInMemoryTesting(configuration);
ISession session = sessionSource.CreateSession()
```

Comment: where do I get the .dll from? what is the name?

Answer (score 0):

Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver, NHibernate, Version=2.1.2.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4

Solution:

Please do some settings in Testsettings:
choose Hosts --> choose Run tests in 32 bit or 64 bit process -->
choose "Run tests in 64 bit process on 64 bit machine"

Thats it. That works or me.

Hoping I could help.

merry coding