# Mvc3 NHibernate SQLite20Driver error

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite, asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate

Has anyone faced this error before. If i try Mvc2, NHibernate, and SQLite it works fine but it breaks with Mvc3

The IDbCommand and IDbConnection implementation in the assembly System.Data.SQLite could not be found. Ensure that the assembly System.Data.SQLite is located in the application directory or in the Global Assembly Cache. If the assembly is in the GAC, use  element in the application configuration file to specify the full name of the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this [example blog post](http://theminimalistdeveloper.com/2010/11/20/how-to-use-fluent-nhibernate-linq-and-sqlite-in-asp-net-mvc-3-project/) (if has the same set up you are describing) and has an example project you can look at.

- NHibernate 3.0
- SQL Lite
- MVC 3
- Fluent NHibernate

I quote from post:-

> In order to use SQLite in our project,
>   download the .NET driver from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/files/SQLite%20for%20ADO.NET%202.0/).
>   Reference the Dlls from your ASP.NET
>   MVC 3 project

Comment: Thats nit working for me. Mvc 2 example code works fine for me but mvc 3 keeps on throwing same exception. Do you have some example with mvc 3, nhibernate, fluent nhibernate, and sqlite.

Comment: mmm, strange, have you seen this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744332/nhibernate-with-windows-application

Comment: can it be something to do with NHibernate.Linq dll's

Comment: You should not reference this if using NH3

Comment: I m not. But surprisingly I think it's something to do with NHibernate.Ling. I would like to create my app in MVC 3 using razor view engine, HTML 5 and NHibernate linq but this combination is just not working for me.